# Add total count in the bargraph

Tags: r, ggplot2, categorical-data

I have a stacked bar graph with 3 variables. How do I add the total number of counts of each in the y-axis. For eg in the picture, I would like to add Rat/rodent (n= 37), Dog (n = 297) and Cat (n=23) on the axis. How do I mention the counts on the axis?

Is it possible only manually? If yes, how do I do that?

My current code

```
sur %>% 
    filter(!(species %in% c("Monkey", "Livestock (cattle/goat/sheep/pig/horse)"))) %>%
ggplot(mapping=aes(y= species_broad, fill=circumstances_bite_broad_intended)) + 
  geom_bar(colour="black" , position = "fill")+
  scale_x_continuous (labels=c("0","25%","50%","75%","100%"))  +
  labs (x="Proportion of responses",y="Pet animal species")+ 
  ggtitle ("Circumstances of bite")+ 
  scale_fill_manual( values =c ("Threatening Engagement" = "darkred" ,
                                "Friendly Engagement" = "red" , 
                                "Practical Engagement" = "#EC7979" ,
                                "Unintentional Human Engagement" = "lightblue" ,
                                "Apparently unprovoked" = "darkblue"))
```

Desired bargraph

[image: desired bargraph]

Comment: Try `... %>% add_count(species_broad) %>% mutate(species_broad = paste0(species_broad, "\n", "(n = ", n, ")")) %>% ggplot(...)`

Comment: Thank you so much. You are a lifesaver. This absolutely works.

Comment: @stefan btw, now the order of the categories have changed in the graph. How do I get them in my desired order.

Desired order:
"Pet dog" , "Unowned dog" , "Dog (unknown status)",
                                "Pet cat" , "Unowned cat" , "Cat (unknown status)",
                                "Rat/rodent" , "Monkey" , "Livestock (cattle/goat/sheep/pig/horse)"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example with the mtcars dataset. This is an addon to @stefan's answer:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  count(cyl, gear) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl), y = n, fill = factor(gear))) +
  geom_col(color= "black", position=position_fill()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) {
    sum_counts <- mtcars %>% 
      count(cyl) %>% 
      group_by(cyl) %>% 
      summarise(total = paste(cyl, "\n", " N=", sum(n))) %>% 
      pull(total) 
    return(sum_counts)
  }) +
  labs (x="Proportion of responses",y="Pet animal species")+ 
  ggtitle ("Circumstances of bite") +
  scale_fill_manual( values =c ("3" = "darkred" ,
                                "4" = "red" , 
                                "5" = "#EC7979")
                     )+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: I don't seem to understand you. Can you let me know how can I use this with my data. I was advised to use scale_y_discrete and label as well, but can't seem to make it work.

Just in case. The two variables are both factors.

Comment: this is just an example. I cant give you your code because we do not have your data. If you could provide the result of (dpur("yourdata")), then I can show with your data.